# Why does C define M_2_SQRTPI constant in <math.h>?

Tags: c, math

In `<math.h>` the constant `M_2_SQRTPI` is defined with the value `2/sqrt(pi)`.

I have never seen this expression used in a formula, so I searched for uses of `M_2_SQRTPI` but I could only found documentation about the constant and no actual uses of it.

Where is the constant used and what is the reason it is defined in `<math.h>` as a mathematical constant?

Comment: It doesn't. `M_2_SQRTPI` is specified by POSIX, but not by ISO C.

Comment: Because committees are weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constant is related to the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

I don't know why it's provided as a constant in <strike>the standard library</strike> POSIX, though. With GCC on a x86-64 system, and by extension on every system conforming to IEEE 754, computing `2.0 / sqrt(M_PI)` yields *exactly* the same double-precision value as `M_2_SQRTPI`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY29CsIwGEVn8xQfFaEF22pxqwqOHYT6MwolJv35IE1qmuogvroxHcTF8Z57uJeFNWPWTlEyMfAS1r3hqKJmS36opaYZSRzD7q6QA1OyN1QaqJTgKGvC1XAVJZiHgg0k0SL9kg4d2Bd5lhJ0fktR@gE8yaTTLle@N4uWK3qR3txZSXE6HM95FqT/@nE8hv6mjd9hMDq6NIOW4N5e1r5ZJWjd21C0Hw)

Even if there was a slight error, the very few people who need the constant could simply define it themselves.

Comment: It is perhaps worth pointing out that even with optimization disabled, gcc produces the exact same code and constant with the portable `1/sqrt(atan(1.))` https://godbolt.org/z/1fofGf

Comment: Just for completeness regarding my previous post: as of today, with clang at `-O2` all functions in the compiler explorer return the same constant, but the call to `atan` is kept and its result ignored. VisualStudio OTOH keeps the function calls even with optimization, not recognizing that the arguments are constant.

Answer (score 1):

It is used in different scientific computations (I've seen it in finance, for instance).

Why do you want it as a constant? Because `sqrt(M_PI)` will not have the same precision as a precomputed value (using more precision for PI to start with). And it makes quite a difference, I've seen the damages of not using it.